# Is it necessary to set border-collapse property to collapse to get rid of any space in between borders?

Tags: html, css, css-tables, border-spacing

Okay, so I have already set the border-spacing to 0px, but there's still just the tiniest tiniest spot where the background of a parent class shows through in between the background of a table descendant and the border of that same table descendant. I've tried making a border cover up the spot. Didn't work. I am currently attempting to create a custom shop layout for my shop on Neopets, but I do not own Neopets so I didn't make the base stylesheets.It wouldn't be that big of a deal, except I'm self-teaching myself CSS so its important to me to have a good understanding of the language. [Part of one of the tables in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP8Ll.png)

Comment: Can you provide a snippet?

Comment: I probably shouldn't provide a snippet of the stylesheets, because Neopets doesn't let anyone access the page that I'm editing unless they have an account and are logged in. But I can provide a snippet of my own code: .sidebar {
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
/* sidebarModule=necessary because otherwise sidebar module will have its own grey border.*/
.sidebarModule {
    border:none;
}
.sidebarTable {
   border:#c72be2 3px solid; 
   border-spacing: 0px;
}

.activePet, .activePet sf, td.neopetPhrase.sf, .activePetInfo
{
    background-color:#8a2be2;
    color:#c72be2;}

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that line is the background of the parent class (.sidebar) and not anything else because back before I removed the background to make the line stand out more, I zoomed in on the page as far as I could go, took a screenshot, then pasted it into paint and used the color picker tool to see what color it was. Sure enough, it was the same as the background color of .sidebar.